# How to observer path change in dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, polymer, polymer-1.0, electron

In my electron app,
I want to cache file path changes with dialog,

```
Polymer({
is:'myelement',
properties:{
  path:{
        type:String,
        defaultValue:'test',
        observer:'_pathChanged'
        }
}   
        _pathChanged: function(newalue,oldvalue){
        alert('new:' + newvalue + 'oldvalue' + oldvalue)
        }
})
```

About dialog

```
           showDialog:function(){
             var remote = require('remote')
             var dialog = remote.require('dialog')
             dialog.showOpenDialog({properties:['openDirectory'],
             function(dirPath){
             if (dirPath){
             this.path=dirPath
             }
           }
          }
```

But,when when choose different files in dialog ,the observer didn't work.

Comment: May be you have to enable two-way binding with [`notify: true`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#notify)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code, first and foremost you need to bind `this` in the callback function you pass to `dialog.showOpenDialog()` to your element instance. And second, `dirPath` is actually an array. So, here's one way to fix those issues:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(
  null, { properties:['openDirectory'] },
  dirPaths => {
    if (dirPaths && dirPaths.length){
      this.path = dirPaths[0];
    }
  }
)
```